# invalid expression sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the data in output variable ,am looking to match the word after `*`,am trying the following way but running into an error, how to fix it?

```
import re
output = """test
          * Peace
            master"""
m = re.search('* (\w+)', output)
print m.group(0)
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testinglogic.py", line 7, in <module>
    m = re.search('* (\w+)', output)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 146, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Comment: Try `m = re.search('\* (\w+)', output)` Added backslash before Star.  Star is used to check for repetitions in regex. Thus to actually match a Star escape character has to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first fix would be to escape the `*`, because you want the engine to treat it *literally* (as an asterisk), so you escape it with a backslash.

Another suggestion would be to use a lookbehind, so you don't need to use another capture group:

```
>>> re.search('(?<=\*\s)\w+', output).group()
'Peace'
```

Comment: @coldspeed - what does `?<=` indicate?

Comment: @Jeremyapple That is the regex syntax for a lookbehind. You specify that that pattern should be present before what you want, but you do not want it captured.